# Entity Framework 4.3 Code First: Set Inherited Property During SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

If I have a DbEntityEntry entry, I access the current values as:

```
var currentValues = entry.State != EntityState.Deleted 
    ? entry.CurrentValues 
    : null;
```

Later, I want to set a property value:

```
currentValues["Created"] = DateTime.Now;
```

I think you can guess what that is for :)

However, the property *Created* exists on a base entity class and I receive an error when attempting to access the property:

> The 'Created' property does not exist or is not mapped for the type
>   'MyEntity'.

This is because the property is in the inherited base class.

How can I set the property?

Many thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `CurrentValues`. Use the entity directly.

```
if (entry.State != EntityState.Deleted && entry.Entity is YourBaseClass) 
{
    YourBaseClass entity = (YourBaseClass)entry.Entity;
    entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Very good, than you! As an aside, is there any way I can get these values populated before validation is run so they are populated with the correct values? I have it in a SaveChanges override but I'd like it to hook in whatever the validation method used (e.g. direct on the entity).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that question.